# Создание динамических групп по исходным данным из Excel (csv) файла

Tags: powershell

Имеется файл Excel, переконвертированный в csv (разделитель запятая).
Требуется периодически его опрашивать,в соответствии с данными создавать (проверять) динамическую группу рассылки в Exchange по полю "Департамент(1,2,3)",удалять пустые группы. Если группа существует,ничего не делать,если не существует то `New-DynamicDistributionGroup` и тд.
Вопрос по первой части скрипта. Импортирую csv.А как проверить данные по столбцу? if exist goto else

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать такую конструкцию:

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\MyFile.csv -Delimiter ',' | ForEach {
    if ($_.ColumnName) {
        $Check += $_.ColumnName # отдаём значение
    }
    else {
        # ничего не отдаём
        # else можно опустить
    }
}

if (!$Check) {
    Write-Host 'Столбец "ColumnName" пуст!'
}
```

Где `ColumnName` - название нужного столбца.

Если нужно получить названия всех столбцов - то:

```
Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Присвоить переменной и её через `foreach`.

Comment: можно пояснения по конструкции if (!$Check)  пожалуйста. у меня просто выводит текст,равный кол-ву строк,независимо есть в столбце данные или нет

Comment: Функция внутри условия `if` будет выполняться, если условие в скобках верно (возвращает значение `true`). Выражение `if ($Check)` будет возвращать `true`, если переменная определена (имеет ненулевое значение). Восклицательный знак перед условием означает, что функция будет выполняться, если условие неверно (т.е. возвращает `false`). То есть, если переменная не определена в нашем случае.